# bubbleSort poker cards

Tags: c, sorting

I am trying to bubbleSort my poker cards for my project and I am stuck and it is not working correctly. Basically, a card is an enum of value and suit. A hand is an array of 7 cards. When I run this code the output is not sorted at all, it is still in its original order as declared in main. Is there a problem with how bubbleSort is implemented or how I am printing it? Any help appreciated greatly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "poker.h"

typedef enum suit{C,D,H,S} suit;
typedef enum value{TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE} value;

typedef struct card {
    value cValue; 
    suit cSuit; 
} card;

typedef struct Hand {
    card cards[7];
} Hand; 

void swap(card * a, card * b)
{
    card t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t; 
}

void bubbleSort(Hand h, int n)
{
    int i,j; 
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(h.cards[j].cValue > h.cards[j+1].cValue)
            {
                swap(&h.cards[j], &h.cards[j+1]); //changed from h.cards[j].cValue                      
            }
        }
    }
}

void printHand(Hand h, int size
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", h.cards[i].cValue);
    } printf("\n");
}


int main()
{
card c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6;

c0.cValue = TEN;
c1.cValue = EIGHT;
c2.cValue = QUEEN;
c3.cValue = FOUR;
c4.cValue = FIVE;
c5.cValue = SEVEN;
c6.cValue = TWO;

Hand h; 
h.cards[0]= c0;
h.cards[1]=c1;
h.cards[2]=c2;
h.cards[3]=c3;
h.cards[4]=c4;
h.cards[5]=c5;
h.cards[6]=c6;

bubbleSort(h,7);
printHand(h,7);
return 0; 


}
```

Comment: Can you put this all together in a [mcve] including the declarations for `hand` and `card`? Make sure your example is compilable. You seem to be missing an `&` and a brace at least in what you have posted so far.

Comment: it looks like `if(h.cards[j].cValue > h.cards[j+1].cValue)` can't really ever evaluate to true, since the `enum` declarations inside your `card` have no relation to the `enum` declarations outside;  in other words, `cValue` and `value` don't know anything about each other.

Comment: Do you really want to swap card values rather then whole cards? What about the suits?

Comment: instead of `enum cValue;` and `enum cSuit;`, try `value cValue` and `suit cSuit`.  Also, @n.m. is correct, if the `swap` were actually called, you would be swapping values, making `TEN C` and `EIGHT D` become `EIGHT C` and `TEN D`, if suits were added.

Comment: You are passing `struct Hand` *by value*. Your function sorts its own copy of a hand, without having any way to influence the calling function.

Comment: I tried using value cValue and suit cSuit in my card struct but it says that the suit and value aren't recognized when I do that

Comment: I fixed my problem, thanks for the help, all that I had to do was pass in the Hand in bubble sort as a pointer and change around a couple things in order to pass Hand in. Fixed problem of passing Hand in by value.

Comment: @Claies in C one needs `enum value cValue;`